# Android Loader in 4.x

Tags: android, android-loader

My question is simple. Is it necessary use Loaders in an app that use Android 4.0 or higher?

I have read that it is useful only if you use Android 3.0 or lower.

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loader are never Necessary. They are simply very useful tools depending on the application you need to develop (and are not deprecated at all).
Take some time to read the doc and decide for yourself.